# Does the content uri points to a specific location in android directory?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Let's say I have this content uri

```
content:///com.test.mypackage/provider_path
```

I'm using **FileProvider** for this content uri and was constructed using

```
Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.test", image);
```

since I'm using FileProvider I need to specify a path in an xml resource;

```
<external-path name="external_files" path="Folder1/"/>
```

From the generated content uri specified above, does the directory structure for this is:

```
com.test.mypackage > Folder1
```

I don't know if the content uri points out to a directory. Btw I'm trying to save an image to a directory using FileProvider.

Answer (score 0):

> A FileProvider can only generate a content URI for files in
>   directories that you specify beforehand. To specify a directory,
>   specify the its storage area and path in XML, using child elements of
>   the  element.

Then, the files you are specifying in XML as

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="myfile" path="mydir/"/>
    ...
</paths>
```

are in your app's private file area, in this particular case the file `myfile` will be in the subdirectory `mydir` under the directory  [getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) points to.